# Extract specific data from website using php

Tags: php, extract

I would like to get data from certain website. 
part of Html as follows:

> `<span class="last">10,750.00</span>`

I would like to get out **10750** without comma and dot.

number 10,750.00 is just an example. This number is changing

Comment: If you know it's 10,750.00 why do you need to extract it?

Comment: Javascript/jquery would be needed to do that unless you have access to the  page on the same server

Comment: You can download the HTML with file_get_contents() then use regex to find the value https://regex101.com/r/efBIbq/1 and lastly do a str_replace to remove the dot and comma. However regex on HTML can be problematic at times. If it's an small HTML file it may work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from this:

```
<span class="last">anything here</span>
```

You could do:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$toSearch1 = '<span class="last">';
$toSearch2 = '</span>';
```

> Get content and prepare search vars

```
$page = strstr($page, $toSearch1);
$page = strstr($page, $toSearch2, true);
```

> This will extract only 'anything' and remove other unnecessary HTML

Then:

```
$page = strip_tags($page);
```

> This will remove HTML tags, or, if you want to try manually

```
$page = str_replace($toSearch1, "", $page);
$page = str_replace($toSearch1, "", $page);
```

Finally

```
$page = str_replace(['.', ','], '' , $page);
```

> Remove dots and commas

```
$page = substr($page, 0, -2);
```

> Remove decimals

```
$page = (int)$page;
```

> You can cast to int, even if PHP will handle automatically if you use the number to do calculations

Fiddle here ==> https://www.tehplayground.com/oqywfzmo2IWJdN0C

Comment: The number 10,750.00 is just an example. Number is changing. I would like to capture it to use it in some equation

Comment: I get blank page. I dont see any echo

Comment: how can I strip commas and dots too look like that: 10750

Comment: sorry I am not lazy just such a newbie :)

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted this answer! Thanks. You can find how here ==> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: when I look code I get <span class="last">10749.99 but I would like to get just number as I would like to use it for further manipulation

Comment: @Grgo If you have <span class="last">10749.99 you can use strip_tags() to remove the tags HTML, see my solution...

Comment: @Grgo Cava's right, I adjusted the code and showed you how to remove the tags with Cava's solution, or manually with _str_replace_. Let me know if everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you have the part of HTML in a variable, you can do this:

```
$html = '<span class="last">10,750.00</span>';
$without_tag = strip_tags($html); // Remove Tags HTML
$number_float = (float) str_replace(',', '', $without_tag); // Remove commas and change to float
echo $number_float; // 10750
```

If you do not have the HTML you can use:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/");
$part = stristr(stristr($html, '<span class="last">'), '</span>', true);
$without_tag = strip_tags($part); // Remove Tags HTML
$number_float = (float) str_replace(',', '', $without_tag); // Remove commas and change to float
echo $number_float; // 10750
```

Comment: The number 10,750.00 is just an example. Number is changing. I would like to capture it to use it in some equation.